# import 3D mesh and output its 2D projections

Tags: python, blender, 3d-modelling, meshlab, 3d-model

**I have to take input 3D models (can be of format .off, .obj, .pcd) and output the 2D projections i.e, the images like screenshots of that model from various angles.** As I want to use them for fine tuning my neural network. So far I have researched a lot but everywhere there is 2D to 3D projections not the opposite. Plus I am a little confused in the difference of **pyWavefront, strawlab, pymesh, Asset**(it can import bunch of 3D formats).

I also have to apply various translations on the obtained images like brightness, reflections etc. if anyone could guide me for that. Then I would really be thankful.

P.S, I would appreciate if any of you also shared some sample code.

Comment: Hey Hi, You got any solution for this. Can you please help me out!

Comment: can you please help me out! @MuhamMad RoshAan MughEes

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I also need such kind of package...